# How to solve for x and y to get x +y summation to reach maximum possible number?

Tags: calculus, optimization, recreational-mathematics, maxima-minima

Sorry if the tags are wrong

The goal here is to solve for x and y but `x + y = 100` with no negative numbers.  Where "max" is simply the maximum output possible.

To figure out the best ratio between x and y, ie 60/40, etc.

The below syntax is not right but will show what I am attempting

`((((.04 * (59/(100+x)) / .6) * x) + ((.04 * (40/(100+y)) / .6) * y))) / 100 = max`

As an example of what a ratio would look like of x being 60% of 100 and y being 40% of 100: (this is not the correct answer but just an example of what i mean by ratios of 100)

`((((.04 * (59/(100+60)) / .6) * 60) + ((.04 * (40/(100+40)) / .6) * 40))) / 100 = 0.022369`

But the goal here is to figure out, what x and y need to be to have the actual result be the highest number possible with `x + y = 100`

**Some notes:** the 100's, all 3, 59, 40, are unrelated to each over if that matters.  All of the other hard coded numbers like .04, .6, etc. can also change depending on the formula.  For instance the formula could change in other sequences to being `((((.04 * (59/(100+x)) / .6) * x) + ((.01 * (10/(120+y)) / .9) * y))) / 100 = max`.  This is a smaller part of an algorithm i am attempting to create where there can be more than 2 equations in one.  In the above, there are technically 2 equations we are trying to combine to find the best dispersing of amounts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm looking to solve for x and y and get the maximum result but x+y =100

Comment: You're saying you want the "best" ratio between $x$ and $y$ but you haven't said what makes one ratio "better" than another.

Comment: The "best" ratio would be the one with the highest result.  I'll add an example

Comment: "Where "max" is simply the maximum output possible."  Maximum output of *what*?  You question does not currently make any sense.  Best ratio for what?  If you have $x=100-\epsilon$ and $y = \epsilon$ then $\frac xy = \frac{100-\epsilon}{\epsilon} = \frac {100}\epsilon -1$ and as $\epsilon \to 0$ we have the ratio $\to \infty$ and we can have a ratio as huge as we want (I can make it over one million percent if I want by making $\epsion < \frac 1{ten\ million}$.  But is that "best"? Is that "max"?  What do you mean.

Comment: That's why I mentioned the syntax was wrong and that max simply means, the maximum output as long as x + y = 100.  You cant do 1,000,000% because the max is around .0225 but i haven't gotten the actual max yet

Comment: There is no maximum.  You can make $x$ as large but less than $100$ as like and make $y$ as small but more than $0$ as you like and you can make the ratio as large as you like.  If $\frac {x_1}{y_1} = M$ just let $y_2 =\frac 12 y_1$ and you get $\frac {x_2}{y_2}=\frac {x_1 + \frac 12y_1}{\frac 12y_1} =2\frac {x_1}{y_1} +1= 2M + 1 > M$.  There is no upper limit.  If $y = 0.00000001$ and $x=99.99999999$ then $\frac xy =\frac{99.99999999}{0.00000001}= 9,999,999,999$.  That's big but we can always make it bigger.

Comment: @fleablood The problem is not to maximize the ratio $x/y$.

Comment: Then what *IS* the problem?  It's not in the least bit clear what OP is asking.  Maximum of *what*?  "best" ration under *what* evaluation of what "good" or bad ratio is?  I have utterly no idea what the OP is asking.

Comment: Look down for what Rob did.  He hit it right on the head.  I am working through it and likely will finish it tomorrow but i already tested his result and its correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to maximize a function
$$f(x,y)=\frac{1}{100}\left(\frac{0.04\cdot59x}{0.6(100+x)} + \frac{0.04\cdot40y}{0.6(100+y)}\right)$$
of two nonnegative variables $x$ and $y$ subject to $x+y=100$.  Equivalently, maximize
$$g(x)=f(x,100-x)=\frac{1}{100}\left(\frac{0.04\cdot59x}{0.6(100+x)} + \frac{0.04\cdot40(100-x)}{0.6(100+(100-x))}\right)$$
subject to $0 \le x \le 100$.  This is a single-variable calculus problem.  Differentiate, yielding
$$g'(x)= \frac{19 x^2 - 31600 x + 1960000}{15(x + 100)^2 (200 - x)^2}.$$
Now solve $g'(x)=0$ by setting the numerator to $0$ and using the quadratic formula, yielding two values of $x$, only one of which is in the interval $[0,100]$. Examine the three critical points, including the end points $0$ and $100$.  For the resulting optimal value $x^*$, which turns out to be approximately $64.529$, you can recover the corresponding optimal $y^*$ as $y^*=100-x^*$.

Comment: wow thanks.  wanted to mention a thanks before i go to bed and will try this tomorrow and get back to you! appreciate the time you put towards this very much (cannot upvote yet, still new)

Comment: I'm curious.  If the models in the formula, `((.04 * (59/(100+x)) / .6) * x)` and the other, were to have kinks in the slope like a Piecewise Curves instead of straight line slopes... would it still be doable to have a formula to solve it as well?

Comment: You would then need to also check the breakpoints (the endpoints of each piecewise segment).

Comment: This obviously isn't the right place but are you by chance freelance for hire, or would recommend a way to get someone to help with this? It's part of a bigger algorithm i have for finances and want to hire for

Comment: Sorry, I am not. There are online freelance hiring sites, but I have never used any. You might also contact a local university.

Comment: Thanks Rob, you have done a lot for me already.  I appreciate the time you put into the problem

Comment: I'm wondering how complex my goal is.  In the concept of scaling to N+Models, with the count of models known ahead of time, plus each model having a kink and different slope params, ie slope steepness, kink breakpoints, etc.  Is this an easy problem? Im curious because i am looking to hire but want to ensure i dont get ripped off.  Anything I should ask, mention, or look for with a mathematician?